# Is there a proven way to efficiently 'apply' a function across a very, very large XML in R?

Tags: r, xml, performance, screen-scraping, large-files

I am quite new to R and especially to XML/HTML. As well I do not have much of an education in computers, software etc, so please forgive some of my ignorance. I am trying to parse and scrape data from some very large XML files (~650 mb) from the HMDB (human metabolome database) website (example xml below with reduced file size). I am trying to grab all synonyms of metabolite compounds using R.

The script I have written works for an XML file up to 32,000 kB, but on a file of ~1.5 mil kB seems to 'crap-out' (for lack of a better term, when using pbsapply the progress bar on some of the sapply lines does not move at all). Obviously this is a much larger file, but I am wondering if it is perhaps my computer which cannot handle the script running on the large file or if there is something I can do with the script itself to alleviate the problem. Or perhaps R is simply not equipped to handle such large files in such a manner?

If it helps for reference, I am running rstudio on R 64X 4.02 with 8 gb of installed ram and a 3.20 GHz processor.

Again sorry if some of this is very basic I am a chemical engineer by education and not very well versed in what some may say is basic computer knowledge. The code is below and thus far it seems to stall at the 'pbsapply' lines of the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(pbapply)

nmlist <- NULL

metabolites <- read_xml("sweat_metabolites3.xml") # make sure the name of the file is correct
namespaces <- xml_ns(metabolites)
rootnodes<-xml_find_all(metabolites, "./d1:metabolite", namespaces)
rootnodes2 <- xml_find_all(rootnodes, "./d1:synonyms", namespaces)


synonyms <-pbsapply(rootnodes2, function(xnode) { xml_text(xml_find_all(xnode, "./d1:synonym"))})
names <-pbsapply(rootnodes, function(xnode) { xml_text(xml_find_first(xnode, "./d1:name"))})
IDs <- pbsapply(rootnodes, function(xnode) { xml_text(xml_find_first(xnode, "./d1:accession"))})

for (i in 1:length(synonyms)){
  
  
  
  aliases <- as.data.frame(unlist(synonyms[i]))
  nm <- data.frame(rep(names[i], dim(aliases)[1]))
  id <- data.frame(rep(IDs[i],dim(aliases)[1]))
  
  names(aliases)[1] <- "Aliases"
  names(nm)[1] <- "Common Name"
  names(id)[1] <- "HMDB ID"
  
  datn <- cbind(id, nm, aliases)
  
  nmlist <- rbind(nmlist, datn)
  
}
```

XML example: it would be this but with thousands of metabolite nodes, and much of the sub-nodes in metabolites have been cut out for brevity.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hmdb xmlns="http://www.hmdb.ca">
<metabolite>
  <version>4.0</version>
  <creation_date>2005-11-16 15:48:42 UTC</creation_date>
  <update_date>2019-01-11 19:13:56 UTC</update_date>
  <accession>HMDB0000008</accession>
  <status>quantified</status>
  <secondary_accessions>
    <accession>HMDB00008</accession>
  </secondary_accessions>
  <name>2-Hydroxybutyric acid</name>
  <cs_description>(+/-)alpha-hydoxy butyric acid, also known as 2-hydroxybutanoic acid or alpha-hydroxybutyrate, b...</cs_description>
  <description>2-Hydroxybutyric acid (alpha-hydroxybutyrate) is an organic acid derived from alpha-ketobutyrate. alpha-Ketobutyrate is produced by amino acid catabolism (threonine and methionine) and glutathione anabold propionic acidemia. More recently it ha...</description>
  <synonyms>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxybutanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxybutanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxybutanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxybutanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>α-hydroxybutanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>α-hydroxybutanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>α-hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>α-hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>(RS)-2-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>(RS)-2-Hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-butanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-butanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-DL-butyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-DL-butyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-N-butyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxy-N-butyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>a-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxy-N-butyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>alpha-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-2-Hydroxybutanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-2-Hydroxybutanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-a-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-a-Hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-alpha-Hydroxybutyrate</synonym>
    <synonym>DL-alpha-Hydroxybutyric acid</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutyric acid, (R)-isomer</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutyric acid, (+-)-isomer</synonym>
    <synonym>2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt, (+-)-isomer</synonym>
  </synonyms>
</metabolite>
</hmdb>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be running into RAM problems. Try `pryr::object_size(rootnodes2)` etc.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I think that is the case. Looks like I'll have to figure a way around them. Cheers.